# Is there a sample for using the heroku api (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, heroku

I'm attempting to use the heroku.api. because the heroku gem has been depreciated.

What I've found is a convoluted dogs breakfast.
Get the api gem, validate the key on one site, use a curl command on another site. Then call the methods..

My app is running on heroku.  I suspect it knows this..  Why make me jump through hoops to us something on their system designed by them/for them.

Anyway..

**Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to do something with this API?**  Like getting the stack I'm on (in code) or getting the number of workers/dyno's I've got running?  Really anything that works... just so I can see how to get it working

Comment: My ultimate goal is to find out how many worker dyno's I've got and scale it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so first thing: the heroku gem is deprecated, but the heroku toolbelt works in a nearly identical fashion. There's no NEED to transition to direct API calls unless you were doing that programmatically in your application. If you were doing that, read on:

Use the heroku-api wrapper.

```
gem install heroku-api
```

Get your API_KEY from https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

If you want to get the stack of the app named "your-app-here"

```
require 'heroku-api'
heroku = Heroku::API.new(:api_key => YOUR_API_KEY)
puts heroku.get_app('your-app-here').body["stack"]
```

Or tell how many processes you currently have:

```
total_processes =  heroku.get_ps('your-app-here').body.count
```

Scale to 2 web processes:

```
heroku.post_ps_scale('your-app-here', 'web', '2')
```

All the info you need: https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

Comment: Only thing I'd add is that the name is the name of the app on heroku.  Like "silver-muffler-1234" or the likes.  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do, but I did the following based on their documentation.

`curl -H "Accept: application/json"   -u :SECRET   -X GET https://api.heroku.com/apps`

https://api-docs.heroku.com/apps

This will return a json object:

```
[
  {
    "id": 000000,
    "name": "example",
    "create_status": "complete",
    "created_at": "2011/01/01 00:00:00 -0700",
    "stack": "bamboo-ree-1.8.7",
    "requested_stack": null,
    "repo_migrate_status": "complete",
    "slug_size": 1000000,
    "repo_size": 1000000,
    "dynos": 1,
    "workers": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. You definitely did misunderstood. (my bad) What am looking for is a tutorial or better yet a sample of code that uses the heroku api. I really just want to scale my workers.  A good question to your answer would be.. "Then what?  I got a json sting... what do I do with it?"